# How can I post updates (commits) in oracle db to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, oracle10g

We have an application (BaaN) on Oracle Database.

We also have an application that is on SQL Server 2005 which uses Oracle (BaaN) contents.

Currently we cache all contents of the Oracle DB to SQL Server nightly through linked server from SQL Server to Oracle.

Thought of using a trigger on Oracle db tables to write contents to Oracle table (DeltaCommits) as the commits occur, and then periodically look for entries in  `DeltaCommits` from SQL Server using a scheduled job.

Or can you please suggest a better way to accomplish this ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use replication to transfer data between Oracle and SQL server.

[This guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966428.aspx) looks like a useful starting point which may help you to decide whether this is a route you want to consider.

Comment: @Ed Harper thanks I think you guided me on right route.. thanks once again . Tony